# Contextual meaning

Tags: contextual-menu, concept

Reading some articles about concepts, I found frequently the word contextual (contextual panel, subcontextual, contextual actions).
Maybe is a newbie's question, but I don't understand very well the meaning of this concept. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 2):

It basically means that everything happens in the same context (e.g. the view does not change). For example, you mention [contextual actions](http://uipatterns.io/contextual-actions):

> The user wants to operate on the data at hand without having to navigate to a different screen.

A contextual panel is a panel that opens when interacting with an element and is usually related to navigation (although you can use it for other purposes, such as an expanding div or some AJAX views).

So the key is that the element contains interactions and all kinds of information related to the context of the page/view you are in (e.g. when you right-click, a contextual menu of actions opens)

This is especially true for UI. Other forms of user experience have multiple contexts, so they have a different meaning beyond this question, being specific to each case and/or methodology

Comment: thanks so much @Devin!